# Parse grandchildren XML to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I have seen various questions & answers but nothing that quite meets my needs.

I have xml flat files (generated by a hardware SCADA system) in the format (edit: sloppy copy & paste previously, fixed now with second `<row>` & there are empty `</STATUS>` fields):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<doc>
    <row>
        <DATE>2022-01-14 06:04:18</DATE>
        <MS>9</MS>
        <POSITION_1>
            <VALUE>53.9850 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            <STATUS>    +</STATUS>
        </POSITION_1>
        <POSITION_2>
            <VALUE>54.3050 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            <STATUS>-F- +</STATUS>
        </POSITION_2>
        <POSITION_3>
            <VALUE>54.0450 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            </STATUS>
        </POSITION_3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <DATE>2022-01-14 06:04:42</DATE>
        <MS>302</MS>
        <POSITION_1>
            <VALUE>54.2600 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            <STATUS>    +</STATUS>
        </POSITION_1>
        <POSITION_2>
            <VALUE>54.4350 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            <STATUS>    +</STATUS>
        </POSITION_2>
        <POSITION_3>
            <VALUE>54.0800 </VALUE>
            <STATUSVALUE>1327104</STATUSVALUE>
            <STATUS>    +</STATUS>
        </POSITION_3>
    </row>
</doc>
```

(actually to POSITION_6) and would like to return a dataframe in the same format that Excel creates when I use Power Query to perform the import and end up with columns:

```
DATE  
MS  
POSITION_1.VALUE  
POSITION_1.STATUSVALUE  
POSITION_1.STATUS  
POSITION_2.VALUE  
POSITION_2.STATUSVALUE  
POSITION_2.STATUS  
POSITION_3.VALUE  
POSITION_3.STATUSVALUE  
POSITION_3.STATUS
```

Excel (with some wrangling) gives:
[image: Expected Excel Output]

At the moment I'm using Pandas read_xml and I'm just getting:

```
                     DATE   MS  POSITION_1  ...  POSITION_4  POSITION_5  POSITION_6
0     2022-01-14 06:02:36  193         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
1     2022-01-14 06:04:18    9         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
2     2022-01-14 06:04:42  302         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
3     2022-01-14 06:05:15  582         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
4     2022-01-14 06:05:46  579         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

as it's not reading below the POSITION_X level in the tree

Comment: First, your sample xml isn't well-formed so please fix that. Second, can you add another `row` to your sample? Finally, can you add the exact expected output from the sample xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the extra `</row>` and IIUC, you can use [elementtree](/questions/tagged/elementtree) to reach the `POSITION_*` *details* :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = [
    dict(
        {fld: row.findtext(fld) for fld in ["DATE", "MS"]},
        **{f"{p.tag}.{details.tag}": details.text for p in row for details in p}
    )
    for row in ET.parse("file.xml").findall("row") # <- put here the actual filepath
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output :

| DATE | MS | POSITION_1.VALUE | POSITION_1.STATUSVALUE | POSITION_1.STATUS | POSITION_2.VALUE | POSITION_2.STATUSVALUE | POSITION_2.STATUS | POSITION_3.VALUE | POSITION_3.STATUSVALUE | POSITION_3.STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-14 06:02:36 | 193 | 53.985 | 1327104 | + | 54.305 | 1327104 | -F- + | 54.045 | 1327104 |  |